# Trying to track changes in Access, but getting error 3825

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am a beginner to Access, but am attempting to track any change made in an Access table. My table is CustomerT, and I am trying to send that data to table CustomerChangeLogT. I have the following:

**DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO CustomerChangeLogT SELECT * FROM CustomerT " & _
"WHERE CustomerID=" & CustomerID**

This gives me *run-time error 3825: SELECT * cannot be used in an INSERT INTO query when the source or destination table contains a multi-valued field*

I know this should be a basic fix, but any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The fix is to not use multi-value fields. You will have to explicitly reference fields for the INSERT and SELECT and exclude any multi-value fields. Running SQL for saving data to multi-value fields requires special syntax and cannot be done in same query with other fields. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-lookup-and-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a#bm7